# Trying to create an updating digital clock in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, clock

So I'm using a package called [timebuilder](https://pub.dev/packages/timer_builder#-example-tab-) that's rebuilding my widget. For DateFormat class I used [this](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package.

```
 final String currentTime = getSystemTime();

 static String getSystemTime() {
   var now = new DateTime.now();
   return new DateFormat("H:m:s").format(now);
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return TimerBuilder.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), builder: (context) {
     print("$currentTime");
     return Text(
       "$currentTime",
       style: TextStyle(
           color: Color(0xff2d386b),
           fontSize: 30,
           fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
     );
   });
 }
}
```

I'm then displaying ClockWidget. My widget is rebuilding fine. But the value of currentTime remains what it initially was when I built my project. Any clues as to why currentTime isn't updating?

Answer (score 8):

Remove `static` from  `getSystemTime()`,

Although I have created a working example from your code,

```
  String getSystemTime() {
      var now = new DateTime.now();
      return new DateFormat("H:m:s").format(now);
  }
```

```
            TimerBuilder.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), builder: (context) {
                print("${getSystemTime()}");
                return Text(
                  "${getSystemTime()}",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff2d386b),
                      fontSize: 30,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                );
              }),
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: TimerBuilder is available in this package : https://pub.dev/packages/timer_builder